# Joining Two Cubes and Get Total Face Area

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, modifiers

I have two identical cubes (1 and 2). Both of them have a face area of 216 units. If I "Join" them with Ctrl+J button and create a single object then

```
face area of new object = face area of Cube 1 + face area of Cube 2 = 2*216 = 432
```

Even when one cube is overlapping 70% with another cube, the joined surface area is still 432.

[image]

I just want the total face area of the new object where the overlapped area will be counted once. The BoolTool does the job for this case, but when one cube has a deleted face (open end, as shown in figure 3) it completely messes everything up and does not perform at all.

However, is there any way to calculate the surface area of the new object when the overlapped area will be considered once only? Joining the objects then just scanning through the surface area or anything else.

The final objects will be cut from a rectangular object (length = 14, width = 14, height = 4). They will be irregular in shapes. The objects I want to merge will be found here

[image]

Comment: Volume calculation is ok for manifold meshes only.

Comment: @lemon can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Volume calculation is the sum of oriented volumes of elementary tetrahedrons. These tetrahedrons have the same summit (say the mesh center) and each tri of the mesh as base. These volumes are oriented depending on the base orientation (+ if normal outside, - if not). If non manifold, volumes are considered several times or can in opposite be absent This can't be (or should it?) an answer as it does not solve what you want to do. But in short if boolean can't make a manifold mesh, I'm doubtful about the possibility of the calculation you want.

Comment: Is this just for cubes/cuboids, as illustrated?

Comment: ....as for  axis aligned as shown could simply calc surface area from bounding box or convex hull.

Comment: @RobinBetts I tried to simplify the question. Actually the final objects will be cut from a rectangular object (length = 14, width = 14, height = 4). They will be irregular in shapes. The objects I want to marge will be found here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/bsZ3mlYG

Comment: @Sourav, if not simple cube, if not overall convex hull "able"... and if boolean dores not work... no solution. But in the specific case from your blend file, you can try: convex hull each volume (to close it), boolean union them all, then calculate the volume... but in this case (blend file) that won't work it seems...